# Django How do I get value of buttons and save it to database

Tags: django, button, model, get

I have multiple buttons which have their own value and I would like to get their values then save it to the database at the same time (I have many to many relationship table).

Example button code;

```
<input id="boonsit" class="btn btn-default" 
       style="font-family: thaisansneue; font-size: 25px;"
       value="boonsit" type="button">
```

The number of the button is different depends on users (after they created maybe 3 for first time but 5 for seconds time )

The button's value will work as 'Username'.

Previously I have implemented some code to add ' Username ' to table as the code below;

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def addProject(request):

    dictData = getInitialVariable(request)
    dictData["USERNAME"] = dictData["USER"].first_name

    if "POST" in request.method:
        txt_projectname = request.POST['txt_projectname']
        txt_desc = request.POST['txt_desc']
        startdate = request.POST['start_date']
        enddate = request.POST['end_date']

        p = projects(
            project_name= txt_projectname,
            description = txt_desc,
            create_date = datetime.datetime.now(),
            start_date  = startdate,
            end_date    = enddate,
            url         = txt_projectname,
        )
        p.save()

        u = User.objects.filter(id=dictData["USER"].id)[0].id
        p.user.add(u)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/projectManagerDashboard/')
```

From the code, I have to create a projects record first and then create a user and make M2M relationship.

Then I would like to create more users and create a relationship with the same project.
What should I have to do??

Comment: have you looked at using some javascript to set values of `<input type="hidden" ... />` on each button click; type=button will not send data to the server, they are just buttons where you need to define what they do. perhaps give us more description on what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: what I exactly do is to make button just be shown username to user and then get its value(which is the username) then save it to the database.

I may use some list to show username instead of button but it does not work with what I have to do so far so I have no choice but use button.

Comment: along with the button simple add a 'hidden' input field.